# Find and print all prime numbers (less than 10000)

Tags: javascript, primes

I want to improve my JS skills by doing challenges. My current challenge is: Write a script which allow user to enter number and then print all prime numbers from 0 to that number.

```js
const PrimeFinder = (function() {

  const PRIMES = [];
  const MAX_RANGE = 10000;

  // cache DOM
  const EL_FIND = document.getElementById('find');
  const EL_RESULT = document.getElementById('result');
  const EL_SEARCH = document.getElementById('search');

  // bind events
  EL_FIND.addEventListener('click', findPrimes);

  function _renderResult() {
    for (let i = 0; i < PRIMES.length; i++) {
      const EL_PRIME = EL_RESULT.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
      EL_PRIME.textContent = PRIMES[i];
    }
  }

  function _resetResult() {
    PRIMES.length = 0;
    EL_RESULT.textContent = '';
  }

  function _validUserInput(N) {
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(N)) &&
      isFinite(N) &&
      N >= 0 &&
      N <= MAX_RANGE;
  }

  function isPrime(n) {
    let start = 2;
    while (start <= Math.sqrt(n)) {
      if (n % start++ < 1) return false;
    }
    return n > 1;
  }

  function findPrimes(val) {
    const USER_INPUT = (typeof val === 'number') ? val : EL_SEARCH.value;
    _resetResult();

    if (_validUserInput(USER_INPUT)) {
      for (let i = 2; i <= USER_INPUT; i++) {
        if (isPrime(i)) PRIMES.push(i);
      }
      _renderResult();

      return PRIMES;
    }
  }

  const publicAPI = {
    isPrime: isPrime,
    findPrimes: findPrimes
  }

  return publicAPI;

})();
```

```css
body,
html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  max-width: 320px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#search,
#find {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
  height: 26px;
  line-height: 26px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #666;
}

#find {
  width: 120px;
}

#search {
  width: 190px;
}

#result {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

#result>div {
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 48px;
  background: coral;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
}

#result div:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Prime Number Finder</h1>
  <input placeholder="" id="search" type="number">
  <button id="find">Find</button>
  <div id="result"></div>
</div>
```

I would like to know what could be done better and why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very nice start! It is clear that you have put some effort into making your code clear and easy to read - it paid off. That said, there are a few things I would recommend changing.

1. Don't take input as a float. This opens up the possibility for confusion without providing any benefit to the user.
2. Include USER_INPUT in the range tested for primes. If I input `5` using the form I only get `2` and `3`, while I expected `2`, `3`, and `5`.
3. Why do you cache `PRIMES` only to reset it every time `findPrimes` is called? If you are going to spend the memory to save a list of primes, you might as well make use of it.
4. I see you have started to optimize your solution by only going up to `Math.sqrt(n)`, but you are still using an inefficient algorithm. I would encourage you to look into the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) as your input is bounded.
5. Don't mix your logic and display code. While for a small project like this it isn't much of an issue, if you want to use `PrimeFinder` somewhere else in your application you would have to rewrite it to strip out all of the page specific code.

---

With this in mind, here is how I would write `PrimeFinder` as a module without handling DOM manipulations.

```js
const PrimeFinder = (function() {
    let PRIMES = [];
    const MAX_RANGE = 10000;

    function _generatePrimes() {
        // Computing 10000 is not much different than computing 500, so fill the entire array.
        let marks = Array(MAX_RANGE + 1).fill(false)
        for (let i = 2; i <= MAX_RANGE; i++) {
            // Already marked as non-prime?
            if (marks[i]) continue;
            // Mark all multiples
            for (let j = i * 2; j <= MAX_RANGE; j += i) {
                marks[j] = true;
            }
            // This number hasn't been marked, and therefore is prime
            PRIMES.push(i);
        }
    }

    function isPrime(n) {
        if (Number.isNaN(n)) throw Error('n must be a number');
        if (n > MAX_RANGE || n < 0) throw Error('n is out of range.');
        if (!PRIMES.length) _generatePrimes();
        // Could be sped up with a binary search.
        return PRIMES.includes(n);
    }

    function findPrimes(upperBound) {
        if (Number.isNaN(upperBound)) throw Error('upperBound must be a number');
        if (upperBound > MAX_RANGE) throw Error(`upperBound must be less than ${MAX_RANGE}`);
        if (upperBound < 0) throw Error('upperBound must be at least 0');

        if (!PRIMES.length) _generatePrimes();

        let index = PRIMES.findIndex(n => n > upperBound);
        // Return a copy of the array so users can't mess with the module
        return index == -1 ? [...PRIMES] : PRIMES.slice(0, index);
    }

    return { isPrime, findPrimes };
}());

function displayArray(parent, items) {
  parent.innerHTML = '';
  items.forEach(value => {
    let el = document.createElement('li');
    el.textContent = value;
    parent.appendChild(el);
  });
}

document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', event => {
  let num = parseInt(event.target.value, 10);
  if (num > 10000) event.target.value = num = 10000;
  if (num < 0 || Number.isNaN(num)) event.target.value = num = 0;
  displayArray(
    document.querySelector('ul'),
    PrimeFinder.findPrimes(num)
  );
});
```

```html
<input type="number" />
<ul></ul>
```

---

The snippet behaves similarly to the provided snippet without mixing DOM logic into the `PrimeFinder` functionality - this makes it possible to easily pull out `PrimeFinder` for use in other projects (even those where the DOM might not exist).

Comment: 2. I forgot to change < into <= in the condition check, now 5 prints 2, 3 and 5. 

5. That sounds reasonable. Could you tell me how would you add a little DOM manipulation to this script? Or at least provide good example of script which is properly separated from logic. I will be grateful

Anyway thank you very much for your comment, it's very helpful. I will refactor my code on the basis of your tips.

Comment: I would make `PRIMES` a `Set` rather than an `Array`.  Otherwise, this is great!

Comment: @KrystianKupiec updated with a bit more code to show how `PrimeFinder` could be used without needing to use DOM manipulation in the module, hopefully this helps. Really the key is trying to separate concerns.

Comment: @kamoroso94 there's a reason `PRIMES` is an array - if it was a set calling `findPrimes` would have more difficulty returning only part of the prime number set. You certainly could use a set, but iterators are a pain.

Comment: @Gerrit0 If `PRIMES` was a `Set`, you would just need to replace `PRIMES.slice(0, index)` with `[...PRIMES].slice(0, index)`, no?

Comment: @kamoroso94 I suppose that's true, though it seems wasteful to iterate through the whole set just to slice some of it off. I guess this is JS in the end. If speed was really important then I'd be using C.

Comment: @Gerrit0 it's still O(n) if you take only up to `index` or take everything and slice of everything after `index`.

Comment: @Gerrit0 thank you really much. I have read about Sieve of Eratosthenes, its really great. I think there should be `<=` instead of `<` in both loop conditional statements because you don't mark 10000 number at this moment, am I right?

Comment: @kamoroso94 to be honest I had no clue that there is something like `Set` I have to learn more about it before I will decide to use it. Thank you.

Comment: Yes @KrystianKupiec, looks like I made the same error I pointed out originally! Fixed. In this case it wouldn't have mattered since 10000 isn't prime, but for the general case it should be changed.